# How to upload a sketch via Arduino Nano

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, isp

I have two Nano boards, but the first one seems the CH340 chipset was burn. :( ,

1. Nano v3, CH340 chipset but unable to identify after connect to my Mac using USB
2. Nano v3, FTDI chipset and in good condition
3. USB to Serial module, using FTDI chipset

I am trying to upload a sketch via a USB-to-Serial module OR another Nano board (or UNO board v3) to my CH340 Nano Board.

**Question:**

1. How to wire them up?
2. Is it need upload a "Arduino as ISP" first?
3. step-by-step tutorial or website talking about this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you have boot loader on your Nano, so you can use your USB to serial, just wire (D0)TX->RX(USB), (D1)RX->TX(USB), GND-GND and supply power to the target Nano. You will need to reboot Nano just before the uploading the code. Uploading is same as usual.

Using other Arduino as ISP needs more wires as well as 2nd Arduino, so i would use above method.

Comment: Firstly, yes, there are boot loader on Nano which chipset was burn one. Means solution A) using USB-to-Serial, B) "Arduino as ISP" board, both able to upload sketch to my broken Nano?

Comment: If only CH340 was burnt than yes, both shall work. CH340 (or FTDI) IC is only to provide USB to Nano D0 & D1 TTL serial conversion, so bootloader can detect and accept new firmware. BTW, there are different CH340 ICs and at least some drivers are incompatible among them. ISP programming method uses MCU SPI programming option so doesn't need USB-TTL conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zuRukW7o0A

- Reboot and press CMD+R immediately after reboot to enter in Recovery Mode
- Open Terminal from Recovery mode
- Run the command csrutil enable --without kext
- Reboot
- Install driver